# Can I get accurate geolocation in Python using HTML5 location tool?

Tags: python, html, geolocation, position

I would like to get my accurate position using a Python script.
I've tried different services based on IP location, which didn't work at all (always miles away from my actual location).

I noticed that the HTML5 geolocation tool is quite accurate on Firefox & Google Chrome, so I decided to use the selenium module to launch a web browser and grab my position from this.

Though I'm facing 2 issues: first, I can't force either Firefox or Chrome to allow location services on a local webpage. Second, I don't know how to grab the result of a javascript function in which I get my coordinates.

Here's what I've done so far:

**geo.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    <p id="demo"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        return "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}



function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>The element below will receive content</p>
        <div id="div" />
        <script type="text/javascript">getLocation()</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

try:
    display = Display(visible=1, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('file:///path/to/geo.html')
    res = browser.execute_script("getLocation()")
    print(res)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    browser.quit()
    display.stop()
```

Do you know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps headless Chrome could help you there. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Comment: Though now that I think about it, unless you have a GPS connected to your computer Firefox and Chrome can also only use your IP. Perhaps their service is just better.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get geo location with IP based.

```
import requests
import json

response_data = requests.get('https://www.iplocation.net/go/ipinfo').text
try:
   response_json_data = json.loads(response_data)
   location = response_json_data["loc"].split(",")
   print "Latitude: %s" % location[0]
   print "Longitude: %s" % location[1]
except ValueError:
   print "Exception happened while loading data"
```

Comment: This API is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

I found Geoclue to be pretty accurate, which may be on your system already. Just install gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 package, then:

```
from gi.repository import Geoclue
clue = Geoclue.Simple.new_sync('something',Geoclue.AccuracyLevel.EXACT,None)
location = clue.get_location()
print(location.get_property('latitude'), location.get_property('longitude'))
```

For more details see my [blog post](https://howtotrainyourrobot.com/building-a-mobile-app-for-linux-part-4-gps-mobile-tracking/).